# Same Sparql with different result using different programs

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

I'm using TopBraid as IDE and Jena in Java. For the same SPARQL query and same file, I'm getting two different result sets.  The ontology can be found here, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/ontology.owl

The SPARQL is:

```
select ?individual ?type ?label where {
  ?individual rdf:type ?type .
  ?individual rdfs:label ?label
  filter (?type in (wo:Kingdom))
}
```

My Java Code:

```java
public class ExeSparql {
    static String prefix = "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
            "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
            "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> " +
            "PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> " +
            "PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> " +
            "PREFIX wo:<http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>" +
            "PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/> ";

    public static ResultSet execute(String queryString){
        queryString = prefix + queryString;
        Model model = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/noor/TBCMEWorkspace/recreate/index.rdf"));
            // Create an empty in-memory model and populate it from the graph
            model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
            model.read(in,null); // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        // Execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
        //qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
        //results = qe.execSelect();
        return results;
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with the Jena code? Using topbraid, the results is fine, while with Jena, the result is wrong.

The result should have been:

| wo:Kingdom | "Animals"                             |
|         | wo:Kingdom | "animalia"

But with Jena, its returning a set of results with incorrect types

Comment: What do you mean by “the result is wrong”?  What were the results?  What did you expect the results to be?  What is the data?

Comment: What Joshua said. Without some idea of what you expect to happen, there's no way to give any advice. How, for example, do you know that it's Jena that's wrong and not vice versa?

Comment: I'm getting two different resultsets using the same SPARQL and same source file. I'm running one SPARQL using top braid for testing, but when using Jena API, I'm getting a different results.

Comment: @user1774937 Yes, but without seeing the data or the query, we cannot distinguish any of the four possibilities:  (i) Jena and TopBraid are _both_ doing something wrong;  (ii) Jena is wrong and TopBraid is right; (iii) Jena is right and TopBraid is wrong; (iv) Jena and TopBraid are both right, but they have output that is different in some way.   It _looks_ like you are _using_ Jena correctly, but the contents of `index.rdf` could still cause some problem, too.

Comment: @user1774937 To make the analogy a bit clearer, the question as it stands now is sort of like saying “I asked Alice and Bill to each solve an arithmetic problem, but Bill's answer not the same as Alice's.  Did Bill make a mistake?”

Comment: @user1774937 Also what version of Jena did you use?  TopQuadrant are typically quite slow and conservative in taking new Jena releases and so you may be seeing the effect of a bug fix/SPARQL spec clarification that has landed in a newer version of Jena that TBC has yet to adopt.

Comment: @user1774937 The current Jena release is 2.10.1 which may make a difference, also you still haven't shown your data so it is still impossible to debug your code

Comment: Ok, which data do you want, the original file?? I have changed to Jena 2.10, this time I am not getting any results at all

Comment: THis is the ontology, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/ontology.owl

Comment: I've edited the question, this is really causing a big problem, if someone can help, that would be great

Comment: Does anyone knows another library I can use instead of Jena??

Comment: @user1774937 Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this query with the data that you provided (I had to add the prefixes):

```
prefix wo: <http://purl.org/ontology/wo/>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?individual ?type ?label where {
  ?individual rdf:type ?type .
  ?individual rdfs:label ?label
  filter (?type in (wo:Kingdom))
}
```

I ran the query using Jena's command line arq with the following results:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data ontology.owl 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| individual                            | type       | label      |
===================================================================
| <file:/nature/life/Animal#kingdom>    | wo:Kingdom | "Animals"  |
| <file:/nature/kingdom/Animal#kingdom> | wo:Kingdom | "animalia" |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The version of Jena (2.10.0) and ARQ (2.10.0) are as follows:

```
$ arq --version
Jena:       VERSION: 2.10.0
Jena:       BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
ARQ:        VERSION: 2.10.0
ARQ:        BUILD_DATE: 2013-02-20T12:04:26+0000
```